# Asymptotic for $\sum a_nb_n$ if asymptotic for $\sum a_n, \sum b_n$ are known

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory

Let us assume that $a_n>0$ and $b_n>0$ for each n. Also let $$ \sum_{n\leq x} a_n \sim f(x)  $$ and $$ \sum_{n\leq x} b_n \sim g(x)  $$. What can we say about the asymptotic on $\sum_{n
\leq x} a_nb_n$?

Comment: Not much. Consider $a_n=b_n=n^{-1/3}$ on the one hand, and $a_{2n}=b_{2n+1}=2n^{-1/3}$ and $a_{2n+1}=b_{2n}=n^{-1/2}$ on the other hand, then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ grow like $x^{2/3}$ in both cases but $\sum\limits_{n\leqslant x}a_nb_n$ grows like $n^{1/3}$ in the first case and like $n^{1/6}$ in the second case.

Comment: You could also consider $a_n = 0$ for $n$ even and $b_n = 0$ for $n$ odd. Then $\sum a_n b_n \equiv 0$, but the asymptotics of $\sum a_n$, $\sum b_n$ can be (more or less) arbitrary.

Comment: @PhoemueX "Let us assume that $a_n>0$ and $b_n>0$ for each n."

Comment: @PhoemueX That's precisely the reason I said both are strictly positive.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read more closely. But still, you can take $a_n$ to decay exponentially for $n$ odd, $b_n$ exponentially for $n$ even and polynomial (or what you like) for the other parities. Since we are only interested in the **qualitative** behaviour, it will not matter much if $a_n = 0$ or if only $a_n \approx 0$ compared to $a_{n \pm 1}$ for $n$ odd/even.

Comment: So I tried applying the circle/delta method to it by writing the sum as \sum_{n<x}a_n \sum_{m<x}b_m \delta(m-n=0) and then writing \delta(m-n=0) as a sum of characters. I'm still lost. You might like to try that approach.

Comment: Where did this problem come from? Maybe there is some missing context as the conclusion seems to be you can say anything about the 'product' series.

Comment: @PhoemueX I see, so the information only on asymptotic is not sufficient to conclude the asymptotic.

Comment: Can we say anything in the case a_n=b_n ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more of the structure of the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$, you cannot say anything about the asymptotic for $\sum_{n\leq x} a_n b_n$, except the simple upper bound $\sum_{n\leq x} a_n b_n\leq f(x)g(x)$. In fact, without any restrictions on $a_n, b_n$ if $f,g$ are monotonic, then for any epsilon, the asymptotic function $h(x)$ for $\sum_{n\leq x} a_n b_n\leq f(x)g(x)$ can be any monotonic function satisfying  $0< h(x)\leq (f(x)g(x))^{1-\epsilon}$.